# How do I modify the size of the text in my page titles?

Tags: customization, title, headers

Sorry for this basic question, but I'm having a hard time editing the size of text for the titles on the pages on my wordpress website. The html is below

```
<h1 class="hero-title"> COVID Visual </h1>
```

[image: banner for Page]

Comment: This really depends on your theme.  Is it a custom theme, a theme that allows you to edit the title size in Customizer, a theme that has options that allows you to edit the title size, a theme that allows you to add your own CSS, or have you created a child theme that you can edit.  It's usually good to provide a bit more info.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I chose the 'highlight' theme from my webhost. I've done some minor editing in the css files....just not sure how to do this one.

Comment: Edit your question to include the HTML that outputs the title - you can just grab this using the developer tools console in your browser.

Most pages use .entry-title or .page-title as the class for the title of pages and posts.

So you'd be looking at something like `.entry-title, .page-title { font-size:24px; }`

Obviously you'd use the font size units you pefer and adjust it to what size you want it to be, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS you want to set it like this:

```
h1.hero-title,
h2.hero-title{
     font-size: 24px;
}
```

Change the `24px` to whatever size actually works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tony. Would this go in the style.css page? I added that example with a very small font size for testing and I'm not seeing stylistic changes.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it would, but you may need to add more specificity or maybe override some existing CSS - it really all depends on the rest of the code and the existing CSS rules.  It's hard for me to tell because I can only see one line.

Comment: Thank you Tony! Afer I added your code above in the Additional CSS in the customizer, it worked! You rock Tony!

Comment: You’re very welcome.